# Build a GQL query (for Google App Engine) that has a condition on ReferenceProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

Say I have the following model:

```
class Schedule(db.Model):
    tripCode = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    station = db.ReferenceProperty(Station, required=True)    
    arrivalTime = db.TimeProperty(required=True)
    departureTime = db.TimeProperty(required=True)
```

And let's say I have a Station object stored in the var `foo`.

How do I assemble a GQL query that returns all Schedule objects with a reference to the Station object referenced by `foo`?

This is my best (albeit **incorrect**) attempt to form such a query:

```
myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Schedule where station = " + str(foo.key())
```

*Once again `foo` is a **Station** object*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be inserting user data into a GQL string using string substitution. GQL supports parameter substitution, so you can do this:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Schedule WHERE station = $1", foo.key())
```

or, using the Query interface:

```
Schedule.all().filter("station =", foo.key())
```

Comment: FWIW, no need to put foo.key() in the second case.  This will work:
Schedule.all().filter("station =", foo)

Answer (score 7):

An even easier thing to do is to change the model definition by adding the 'collection_name' field to the ReferenceProperty:

> station = db.ReferenceProperty(Station, required=True, collection_name="schedules")

Then you can just do:

> foo.schedules

whenever you want to get all the stations' schedules.