# How to query on ReferenceProperties?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Assume:

```
class Pet (db.model):
  owner = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
  vet = db.ReferenceProperty(Vet)
  name = db.StringProperty()
```

How do I query for Pets that have user Owner A and Vet B?  I assume the references in the Pet class are keys.  Please post a reference if you know a good one - I could not find a good example in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are keys.

And you can get them from a model instance or you can generate them from scratch.

**Filter on a key:** [Question GQL ReferenceProperty filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852055/build-a-gql-query-for-google-app-engine-that-has-a-condition-on-referenceproper/854910#854910)

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE owner = :1 and vet = :2", owner.key(), vet.key())

Pet.all().filter("owner =", owner.key()).filter("vet =", vet.key())
```

**Create keys using from_path:** [Datastore key.from_path](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html)

```
Key.from_path(kind, id_or_name, parent=none, namespace=None, **kwds)
Key.from_path('Pet', 'Dr Vet')
Key.from_path('Pet', 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found the solution was straight forward:

```
q = Pet.all()
q.filter("owner", owner)
q.filter("vet", vet)
q.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [Gqlquery](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#Introduction) class:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE owner = :1 AND vet = :2", user.key(), vet.key())
```